# PHP foreach an assemblage of data string

Tags: php

I've an string contain multiple `block data` string, and I want to parse every one of them to an individual file

Here's an example of the string:

```
[
    ['test', 'lol'],
    ['test2', 'lol2']
]
[
    ['test32', 'loDl'],
    ['test32', 'loDl2']
]
[
    ['tes23t', 'loDEl'],
    ['testDE2', 'lolDE2']
]
```

I want to transform everything like this

```
[
    ['foo', 'bar'],
    ...
]
```

to an array

What I've tried: using explode and foreach

```
<?php
$list = "[
    ['test', 'lol'],
    ['test2', 'lol2']
]
[
    ['test32', 'loDl'],
    ['test32', 'loDl2']
]
[
    ['tes23t', 'loDEl'],
    ['testDE2', 'lolDE2']
]";
$arr = explode("\n", $list);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
   if($value == "]") {
    echo "accepted: $value newline<br>";
   } else {
    echo "refused: $value newline<br>";
   }
}
?>
```

Here I'm trying to detect the "]" character to make another foreach, but the result is this

```
refused: [ newline
refused: ['test', 'lol'], newline
refused: ['test2', 'lol2'] newline
refused: ] newline
refused: [ newline
refused: ['test32', 'loDl'], newline
refused: ['test32', 'loDl2'] newline
refused: ] newline
refused: [ newline
refused: ['tes23t', 'loDEl'], newline
refused: ['testDE2', 'lolDE2'] newline
accepted: ] newline
```

So, how can I parse  every `block data` string to an array? Thanks

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service** You have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: Just a small point, **thats not a valid JSON String** Be more specific about what this string **actually looks like**

Comment: @RiggsFolly Post edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `preg_split` on the ending `]`:

```
$list = file_get_contents('RN7rK');

$jsons = preg_split('/\]\s*(?=\[)/', $list, null);
foreach ($jsons as $json) {
    $json .= ']';
    print_r(json_decode($json));
}
```

Comment: Your solution is working, but If the number of values in something like that `["lol", "xd" "haha"]` it's not working, so how can I make it working for any number of values ?

Comment: Can you post more examples, the number and single vs double quote matters

Comment: Here's one example of a code that contain a lot of values http://pastebin.com/ieUvYTxc

Comment: PS: I only need the 10 first values

Comment: I know that's a valid json, but in the string that I have there's a lot of strings like that, so how can I separate them to make a lot of valid json ? then I will foreach and json decode them

Comment: please provide a more complete example

Comment: Thank you for your help and efforts! That is what I was looking for

Comment: json_decode is not working with your code (when I print_r nothing happens). What's wrong ? PHP code http://pastebin.com/mBRWNvKT and data.txt (full) : https://paste.ee/r/RN7rK

Comment: the issue is the jsons in your new file is not separated by newline. see updated answer.